# Magento 1.6: This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I have a dev site on **magento 1.6** . Now I am trying to create a local installation with this dev site files and DB.

I have changed the `web/unsecure/base_url`, `web/secure/base_url` and `web/url/redirect_to_base` to 0.
I have also cleared `var/cache` and `var/session`.
But I am still getting:

> This webpage has a redirect loop issue.

Tell me please how to resolve this error?

Comment: Did you refresh the Custom URL index in Index Management ? by the way, why do you install such ancient version ?

Comment: @Shyam Try to replace the .htaccess file with the default Magento .htaccess file.Do not forget to write http:// when you are modifying the url.Are you trying to setup your site on linux or windows server?